# Kivy access item in ListView

Tags: kivy

I am new to kivy and I would like to acess the list items from ListView (or its adapter). But I could not find any examples anywhere.

Here is a sample code and what I want to do:

```
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView
from kivy.adapters.simplelistadapter import SimpleListAdapter
from kivy.uix.label import Label

list_adapter = SimpleListAdapter(data=[str(i) for i in range(10)],cls=Label)
my_list = ListView(adapter=list_adapter)

#How do I access and modify the Label items in my_list?
#I tried list_adapter.get_view(index), but it does not seem to give me
#access to the items themselves, just copies...
```

Sorry, if I am making some obvious mistake, but I am still learning kivy basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created `data` property containing labels with numbers from 0 to 9. Access it like any list `list_adapter.data[0] = "test"`.

---

If you want to access the Label objects directly, then use `get_view` function:

```
class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        list_adapter = SimpleListAdapter(data=[str(i) for i in range(10)], cls=Label)
        my_list = ListView(adapter=list_adapter)
        list_adapter.data[0] = 'test'
        for i in xrange(list_adapter.get_count()):
            print 'object:', list_adapter.get_view(i),
            print ', text:', list_adapter.get_view(i).text
        return my_list
```

Comment: But this gives me access to my original objects, not the Label objects created by ListAdapter.
As you mentioned, in my example, list_adapter.data[0] will give me my original string and not the Label generated with this string...